# Why am I getting an undefined property from an imported enum

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript with react (created using create-react-app) and at run-time I get an error *Cannot read property 'Customer' of undefined*. with the following module loads

```
import { Roles } from '../common/utils';
export const defaultUser: UserDetails = {
    name: '',
    roles: [Roles.Customer],
}
.....
```

Comment: what does the export of `Roles` look like in `utils`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony's comment set me on the right path. Thanks.
I had:

```
export enum Roles {
    Administrator = 'Admin',
    Agent = 'Agent',
    Customer = 'Customer',
}
```

changing that to the following fixed the issue.

```
export const enum Roles {
    Administrator = 'Admin',
    Agent = 'Agent',
    Customer = 'Customer',
}
```